# Почему возвращается размер указателя

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pr(int *a)
{
    cout << sizeof(a);
}
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3}; 
    pr(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Почему возвращается размер указателя, (8)
А не размер массива? (12)

Comment: `void pr(int *a)
{
    cout << sizeof(a);
}` - как объявлена переменная `a`? Что такое `int*a`, как не объявление указателя? Так почему размер `a` должен не быть размером указателя?... Массив при передаче в функцию преобразуется в указатель.

Comment: Ну дык вы передали в `sizeof` указатель, а не массив. Все логично.

Comment: Это называется type erasure - стирание типов. Передача массивов в функции один из вариантов такого стирания. Ещё один, например приведение указателя конкретного типа (`int*`) к типу `void*` или к `char*` для побайтной работы с памятью.